# Matlab : x v/s y plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a function y=1-exp(c) ,where as the range of x is defined. The plot is to be between x and the function y. The plot just shows just 1 point instead of showing a series of points exponentially.I am new in Matlab.Sp,please help me where I am going wrong Here is the code:

```
   for x = -10:0.25:10

   if(x>0)

   c=-6*x;
   m=exp(c);
   y = 1-m  

   end
   plot(x,y,'o')
   xlabel('x') 
   ylabel('y') 
   title('Plot')
   end
```

Comment: What is y when x <= 0? 
P.S.: That happens because you are plotting several times, and each time you use the plot command in a figure it clears the figure unless you previously use "hold on;"

Comment: y=0 then . So, I should use the plot command after for loop?

Comment: You shouldn't use a loop at all - see the answer by nate, that is the correct way to do it. Type x = -10:0.25:10 in the command line without the semicolon and see what the output is. Functions in Matlab tend to operate on entire vectors so exp(x) will apply exp() to each element of x. This allows you to eliminate many loops which are often less efficient in matlab.

Comment: You should avoid for loops as much as you can in Matlab. I was simply explaining why your code has that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
x = -10:0.25:10; % define the x vector
c=  -5*x.*(x>0); % using a  logical condition the 'if' is avoided
y = 1-exp(c);    % calc y given c

plot(x,y,'o')
xlabel('x') 
ylabel('y') 
title('Plot')
```

no 'for' loop or 'if' needed...

Comment: Thanks, problem solved  but can you please tell me what was wrong with the for loop and if statement (just for the sake of learning I want to know)

Comment: As I explained above, there are two main reasons: 1) Every time you use the plot command, the current figure is cleared. To plot "over" some figure you need to use "hold on;" 2) Your code would work with a for loop but you in Matlab that's extremely slow and you should avoid for loops. By using an array "x" and an array "y", you're able to plot at once all the values in x against the values in y.

Comment: every iteration you were just saving a single value of y and plotting it against a single value of x. The plot was getting cleared each time. In matlab it is more correct to create a vector of x and y and then plot the enitre vectors in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the for loop. It is resetting the value of y and re-ploting that one point each loop. You don't need that loop at all. This code will do the trick for y = 1-exp(A*x)

Edit (2012-10-30) OP says y is zero for x<=0. [@Nate's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292464/nate) code in the answer above is probably best, but here I use logical indexing to show a different way to do the same thing.

```
x = -10:0.25:10; % <vector>
y = zeros(size(x)); % prealocate y with zeros and make it the same size as x
y(x>0) = 1 - exp(-5*x(x>0)); % only calculate y values for x>0
plot(x,y,'o')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
title('Plot')
```

Comment: the OP wants y = 0 if x < 0 (see comments) so x = x(x>0) should be x = x.*(x>0) so this answer is basically identical to nates.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification [@Dan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724/dan), I missed the OP's comment that they wanted y=0 if x<=0. I fixed the code in my answer, but provided an alternate to [@nate's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1292464/nate) for variety.